# How to add missing rows in dataframe by comparing values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

Hi I am using python pandas for dataframes,I have data something like as followed:

Employee-ID       Time-slot      Calls-received         Prod-sold

1                         14:30:00                          10                         1

1                                     15:00:00                           15                          3

1                         15:30:00                           10                     2

1                         
   16:00:00                           8                       2

1                         16:30:00                          10                      0

2                         14:30:00                          10                      2

2                        
   15:00:00                          15                       3

2                          16:30:00                          10                     2

2                           17:00:00                          10                     0

I have 10,000 employee and ideally there should be 16 time slots for each employee but time slots are missing for some employees, like employee 2 time slot 15:30:00 and 16:00:00 is missing I wish to add new rows and with missing time slots and  zero values for 'calls-received' and prod-sold. Something like that:

2                           14:30:00                          10                                  2

2                            15:00:00                          15                                        3

2                             15:30:00                          0                            0

2                           16:00:00                          0                             0

2                           16:30:00                          10                              2

2                                     17:00:00                          10                                        0

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a code writing service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the links it contains. Pandas has pretty robust datetime functionality - spend some time with the docs and try to come up with a solution: [Working With Missing Data](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#working-with-missing-data); [Time Series/Date Funtionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-series-date-functionality)

Comment: If you plan on using Pandas, it would be worthwhile to invest some time watching and working through the examples presented in this talk -[Pandas From The Ground Up](http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015)